# How do I implement swipe-to-throw in Andengine?

Tags: android, physics, andengine, touch, gestures

I have a ball sprite and I apply physics to it when the user swipes on it. I'd like the ball to start moving in the direction of the swipe.

How can I do this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about debugging your code for you.

Comment: when ever I swipe on the sprite it must go in that direction only,i have added physics to that sprite.

Comment: Instead of including your non-working code and asking "how do I fix this". Why don't you tell us what your algorithm is, or ask how to implement the specific part of the algorithm that's not working. It's not clear from your question what the problem with the code is, this makes it far more difficult to debug.

Comment: @Byte56 : ThankS bro ,I have edited my question. can you help me out with that ?

Comment: I made some more clarifications and voted to re-open. Some more *conceptual* details on what you've tried or where you're getting stuck would help. For instance: Have you got swipe detection working? Are you using your own physics or a library like [Box2D for AndEngine](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension)? (It just helps "aim" an answer.)

Comment: @Anko : Yeah I'm using BoX2D,AndEngine Library.
I tried to get the swipe direction by using onAreaTouched(TouchEvent, ITouchArea, float, float),But it's not working properly.

Answer (score 1):

I have never written code for andengine but some pseudo like this may work:
**OnTouch:** You  want to get the touch position.
**OnRelease:** You want to get the release position.
Theese two points can be used to create a direction vector. (The angle in between the points).

If you want, you  can also use the distance between the points as force, but most likely you would like to use know how fast the user moved his finger, and you could initialize a timer on touch and stop it on release to know how fast moved his finger, and then multiply the delta-time with some speed variable.